# NVM not start downloading, fails download after sometimes

Tags: 20.04, bash, wget, curl, sh

recently i have installed Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS x86_64

when i hit the command `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.5/install.sh | bash` it does not start downloading, it just increments the Time spent and after 2 minutes and 10 seconds it stops downloading with this error

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:10 --:--:--     0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

i have tried installing older version as well `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash` but got the same issue

My system configuration is

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS x86_64 
Host: 81N3 Lenovo IdeaPad S145-15AST 
Kernel: 5.15.0-79-generic 
Packages: 1947 (dpkg), 10 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.0.17 
CPU: AMD A6-9225 RADEON R4 2C+3G (2) @ 2.600GHz 
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics 
Memory: 2385MiB / 6534MiB
```